# Suspicious Shadowing by a Type Parameter while defining Scala 3 Type Class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, extension-methods, typeclass, scala-xml

I'm trying to implement some small quality-of-life improvements around an XML parser, basically trying to ape the way Circe looks like for Json parsing in Scala.
The idea then would be to come up with a type class definition along these lines

```scala
type ParseResult[T] = ???

trait XMLCodec[T]:
  extension(t: T)
    def toXML: Elem

  extension(xml: Elem)
    def as[T]: ParseResult[T]  // <- this fails to compile
```

Except that, as stated in the title, I get a `Suspicious Shadowing by a Type Parameter`.

I could of course remove the `[T]` from that line as in

```scala
trait XMLCodec[T]:
  //...

  extension(xml: Elem)
    def asObject: ParseResult[T]  // <- works fine
```

The above is fine, but I have concerns about name collision when more than one implementation of the same type class is present in any given context.
Is there an easy way out of this that I'm missing?

Comment: `<- this fails to compile` Can't reproduce. The code seems to compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/BmKCLGwcSQG3haB7nLD7iw/3 Probably you missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `as[T]` has its own type parameter independent of the `XMLCodec[T]` type parameter then what is the reason to put the extension method `as[T]` inside the type class `XMLCodec[T]`?

Maybe you can have a type class

```
trait XMLCodec[T]:
  extension (t: T)
    def toXML: Elem

  def toParseResult(xml: Elem): ParseResult[T]
```

and a standalone extension method

```
extension (xml: Elem)
  def as[T](using codec: XMLCodec[T]): ParseResult[T] = codec.toParseResult(xml)
```

Comment: Yup, this does it. Seems obvious in hindsight. Thanks!